# texturing a sphere using LWJGL opengl?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I want to draw a sphere and texture it,i draw it by triangles and when i am trying to texture it some triangles aren't covered

i am using this function to generate the Coordinates

```
public void createSolidSphere()
    {
        float R = (float) (1./(float)(rings-1));
        float S = (float) (1./(float)(sectors-1));
        int r, s;
        int texCoordsIndex = -1;
        int verticesIndex = -1;
        int normalsIndex = -1;
        int indicesIndex = -1;
        for(r = 0; r < rings; r++) for(s = 0; s < sectors; s++) {
            float y = (float)Math.sin( -Math.PI/2 + Math.PI * r * R );
            float x = (float)Math.cos(2*Math.PI * s * S) * (float)Math.sin( Math.PI * r * R );
            float z = (float)Math.sin(2*Math.PI * s * S) * (float)Math.sin( Math.PI * r * R );

            texcoords[++texCoordsIndex] = s*S;
            texcoords[++texCoordsIndex] = r*R;

            vertices[++verticesIndex] = x * radius;
            vertices[++verticesIndex] = y * radius;
            vertices[++verticesIndex] = z * radius;

            normals[++normalsIndex] = x;
            normals[++normalsIndex] = y;
            normals[++normalsIndex] = z;
        }
        for(r = 0; r < rings; r++) for(s = 0; s < sectors; s++) {


            indices[++indicesIndex] = r * sectors + (s+1);
            indices[++indicesIndex] = (r+1) * sectors + (s+1);
            indices[++indicesIndex] = (r+1) * sectors + s;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've to draw quads rather than triangles. A quad can be formed by 2 triangles.
Each quad consist of 4 points:

```
0: r * sectors + (s+1)
1: (r+1) * sectors + (s+1)
2: (r+1) * sectors + s
3: r * sectors + s
```

This 4 points can be arranged to 2 triangles:

```
    2           1
     + +-------+
     | \ \     |
     |   \ \   |
     |     \ \ |
     +------+  +
    3           0
```

You've to add 6 indices for each quad rather than 3:

```java
for(r = 0; r < rings; r++) for(s = 0; s < sectors; s++) {

    // triangle 1
    indices[++indicesIndex] = r * sectors + (s+1);
    indices[++indicesIndex] = (r+1) * sectors + (s+1);
    indices[++indicesIndex] = (r+1) * sectors + s;

    // triangle 2
    indices[++indicesIndex] = r * sectors + (s+1);
    indices[++indicesIndex] = (r+1) * sectors + s;
    indices[++indicesIndex] = r * sectors + s+;
}
```

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work , when i am running ;the window closing automatically and very fast

Comment: @Mohamad_Hn, Have you tried it in a debugger? If the program closes instantly that could be an uncaught exception.

Comment: @Mohamad_Hn Is the index array (`indices`) large enough? You've to double the size!

Comment: when i edit the code and add the new part there is an exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 40000
 at Project.Sphere.createSolidSphere(Sphere.java:117)
 at Project.Sphere.<init>(Sphere.java:61)
 at engineTester.Main.main(Main.java:134)
@Romen

Comment: @Mohamad_Hn Pleas read the comment above. If you have twice as many indices, then the buffer size needs to be doubled. The index buffer (named `indices`) is designed to hold 3 indices per quad, but now it has to hold 6 indices per quad.